# Strange 2x2 Inverted slope with hollow center Identification

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, slope

I have a brick that is similar to a 45 degree inverted slope 2x2 except where the un-sloped flat face should be there is a rectangular cavity into the brick

```
   _______
  /   ____|
 /   |
/     ----|
--HH---HH-
```

that is a rough cross-section of what it looks like where the H's represent the studs on the bottom

Comment: Does it have any numbers on the bottom?

Comment: no, but now that i look closer it has the letters TY and an infinity symbol.... TYCO perhaps....

Comment: If it's TYCO, and not LEGO, piece-id is gonna be nigh-impossible. As a clone brand, they can't afford good documentation like TLC.

Answer (score 2):

Could be one of the bricks used at section 7 and 9 of this Tyco Super Blocks set:

[image]

Source: http://bricker.ru/instructions/download/Tyco%20Super%20Blocks/5281-2.pdf